# how to make Classic Javascript Pop up box with drop down list?

Tags: javascript, button, custom

Hi I've created a custom button that fills in an email template. I'm trying to add an drop down list so the user can select the template they want.

Right now it uses a prompt pop up window, where as I would like it to be a drop down. Any help would be great thank you.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}

var methodSelection = prompt("Please enter which method");
{

if(methodSelection == '1')
        location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/&p3_lkid={! Deal_Pipeline__c.Id }&template_id=template1');

if(methodSelection == '2')
        location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/&p3_lkid={! Deal_Pipeline__c.Id }&template_id=template2');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It looks like you aren't using Visualforce tags or Lightning.  If that's the case, just use an HTML select tag, and, in your javascript function that handles the button click, reference its value by using

`document.getElementById("mySelect").value`